Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Italian Language Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Which one is correct: "ho dimenticato" or "mi sono dimenticato"?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Why was the "-ista" suffix used for traditionally male jobs? Is it correct to use "-isto" variant?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Stress on Italian proper names

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Placement of Adverbs

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


"Mi sarei aspettata" versus "mi sarei aspettato"

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


'tangentopoli', 'concorsopoli', 'sanitopoli', and so on

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


Punti di sospensione per un elenco: come utilizzarli in italiano

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Vi piace 'la quadra', o preferite 'la quadratura'?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Usare 'presso il' e 'al' correttamente

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Difference between 'vuotare' and 'svuotare'

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


at least for the Q&A I evaluated, the situation is good: all answers were excellent or at least at par with what I could found elsewhere :-)
